# How much is customary to tip drivers in Georgia?

Tags: georgia-country, tipping

I.e. foreigners travelling with a tour agency based in Georgia. In their quotations they mention explcitely that the quote does not include tips for the drivers.

How much is it customary to pay? i.e. not by locals but by foreigners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the tour operator:

> Though we pay a good salary to our staff, clients usually tip them for
>   their good job. Generally on a tour for 2  persons they tip minimum
>   US$ 20 - $25 total per day for the guide and about $15 - $20 total per
>   day for the driver. However, it is upon you to add more or pay less.

It is nevertheless quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

While I've never been to georgia, when I was [touring eastern europe with friends](https://expatexplore.com/tours/eastern-highlights/), we usually tipped all our drivers 5% - 10%. Depending on where you're travelling from, if you can afford to let go of a few coins then whether it's customary or not, it's a good idea.

Comment: What about not tiping? Is that too bad? i.e. why do not the tour operators include the tips in the salaries?

Comment: Not tipping can be passable (that's not to say it's a good idea), but often if a tourist isn't tipping, in my experience people don't view it as "bad", they often just assume the tourist isn't aware of the customs - that's not to say, also, that they won't be disappointed.

When I'm talking about drivers, I mean for taxis we took ourselves, not the tour bus drivers